# Latest Windows 10 Will Not Deploy Printers Per Computer

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, network-printer, windows-server-2016

I have a small offline network with a number of Windows 10 Clients patched to the latest and greatest  using Windows 10 (21H1). They are in a GPO with Deployed printers from our Windows Server 2016 print server. There are 4 printers.

Through GPO they are deployed "PER COMPUTER". When I do a gpupdate /force they do not installed. Recently I found that they show up if I deploy them "PER USER". Previously before the 21H1 upgrade the printers would deploy "PER COMPUTER" without a problem.

What changed in 21H1 that they only show up PER USER and not PER COMPUTER? There is no errors in the Application Log when applying GPOs. I can get to the share on the Printer Server directly and install the printer that way but it will not deploy "PER COMPUTER" through GPO.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I was looking on Serverfault and a related question was asked but was pushed to Super User. This question is different but sort of on the same line.

Comment: There is a lot of overlap between SF and SU. In general, if it's for a single-user or home (ad-hoc) network environment, it's probably for SU. For a business/domain network, it's probably SF. Yours sounds like the latter, hence my suggestion to go to SF.

Comment: If someone could migrate it that would be great then.